# Changing image of ImageButton on press and release

Tags: android, xamarin.android

In Mono For Android, I have an ImageButton and I want to change its image while user is holding the button. And when user release the button image should change to pervious image. I am trying with the code below but nothing happens:

```
    private void _goForward_KeyPress(object sender, View.KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if(e.Event.Action == KeyEventActions.Down)
        {
            _goForward.SetImageResource(Resource.Drawable.arrowUpGreen);
             //Then do some stuff
        }
        else
        {
            _goForward.SetImageResource(Resource.Drawable.arrowUpRed);
            //Then do some stuff
        }
    }
```

I am not sure if I am doing this with the right event. What event usualy should be used in this case?

Comment: you mean you are setting the background image of button????

Comment: No the actual image of the ImageButton

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to attach your method to the button's [`KeyPress`](http://androidapi.xamarin.com/?link=E%3aAndroid.Views.View.KeyPress) event for it to be called, since the wiring doesn't happen automatically:

```
_goForward.KeyPress += _goForward_KeyPress;
```

**EDIT**

Oops, I should have read the question a little more closely the first time. Since you're trying to hook into when the button is touched, you want the [`Touch`](http://androidapi.xamarin.com/?link=E%3aAndroid.Views.View.Touch) event instead:

```
_goForward.Touch += _goForward_Touch;
```

and

```
private void _goForward_Touch(object sender, View.TouchEventArgs touchEventArgs)
{
    if (touchEventArgs.Event.Action == MotionEventActions.Down)
    {
        Toast.MakeText(this, "down", ToastLength.Short).Show();
    }
    else
    {
        Toast.MakeText(this, "up", ToastLength.Short).Show();
    }
}
```

Comment: I have already attached the KeyPress event. But the conditions in the event handler does not seems to do anything.

Answer (score 5):

**Try this:**

**Use the selector for this**

**Say its name as: background_drawable.xml**

```
<selector
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">     
    <item       
        android:drawable="@drawable/YOUR_IMAGE_WHEN_PRESSED"
        android:state_pressed="true" />
    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/YOUR_IMAGE_WHEN_FOCUSED"
        android:state_focused="true" />
    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/YOUR_IMAGE_WHEN_NOT_ENABLED"
        android:state_enabled="false" 
        />
    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/DEFAULT_IMAGE_WHICH_YOU_WANT_ALWAYS" />
</selector>
```

**And in you main.xml file**

```
<ImageButton 
            android:background="@drawable/background_drawable"/>
```

Comment: I really want to do it dynamiccly in code because in each press release I want to execute some more codes.

Comment: So for that you can register you ImageButton to onClickListener OR OnLongClickListener mate

Comment: This is for sure the right answer.  The selector method that nick suggests will only effect the look of the button (ie. change the button when it is pressed).  Then you will need to register a listener for the other events, and act appropriately in code (execute your other methods).  For sure this is the best approach.